# Append to array in swift - has no member append?

Tags: swift, append, nsarray

What am I doing wrong in this code?

and why do I get the error ?

> "Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'append'"

```
    static func saveUserData()
    {
        let item:NSDictionary = ["TIME":"12:00","LOCATION":"here"]
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let filePath = documentsDirectory + "/datafile.dat"
        var readArray:NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: filePath)

        if var array = readArray {

            print("loaded array - appending..." )

           // PROBLEM IS HERE 
             var damnArray:NSMutableArray = array
             damnArray.append(item)
         } else {
           //
         }
    }
```

Comment: append it is only available to Swift native array type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you are using `NSMutableArray`, you need to use `addObject`

```
damnArray.addObject(item)
```

`append` is used with swift array like this way

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr.append(5)
```

For more detail about swift `array` check this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) or this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_arrays.htm).

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between declaring an array like `var arr : [[String : Any]]?` and `var arr = [[String : Any]]()`. I am so much confused in these. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your had declared dammArray as NSMutableArray. So there is no method append is available. Append is available in swift array object.

```
 var damnArray:NSMutableArray
 damnArray.addObject(item)
```

or

```
 var damnArray = [NSDictionary]()
 damnArray.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your answer and syntax this worked for me thanks, in my code which is:

```
@IBAction func btnSend(_ sender: UIButton)

{

    //data.append(tfData.text!)

    data.add(tfData.text!)
    tblViewList.reloadData()

    tfData.resignFirstResponder()
}
```